# 128-bit rotation using ARM Neon intrinsics

Tags: c, rotation, intrinsics, neon

I'm trying to optimize my code using Neon intrinsics. I have a 24-bit rotation over a 128-bit array (8 each `uint16_t`).

Here is my c code:

```
uint16_t rotated[8];
uint16_t temp[8];
uint16_t j;
for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
     //Rotation <<< 24  over 128 bits (x << shift) | (x >> (16 - shift)
     rotated[j] = ((temp[(j+1) % 8] << 8) & 0xffff) | ((temp[(j+2) % 8] >> 8) & 0x00ff);
}
```

I've checked the gcc documentation about [Neon Intrinsics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html) and it doesn't have instruction for vector rotations. Moreover, I've tried to do this using `vshlq_n_u16(temp, 8)` but all the bits shifted outside a `uint16_t` word are lost.

How to achieve this using neon intrinsics ? By the way is there a better documentation about GCC Neon Intrinsics ?

Comment: `armcc` has `__ror` intrinsic

Comment: What about using inline assembly with the `ROR` ARM instruction?

Comment: I prefer to avoid assembly. By the way I'm using GCC so no armcc !

Comment: GCC also supports ARM assembly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some reading on [Arm Community Blogs](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/684-coding-for-neon-part-5-rearranging-vectors/), I've found this :

[image: Neon Arm Bitwise Rotation]

> VEXT: Extract
>   VEXT extracts a new vector of bytes from a pair of existing vectors. The bytes in the new vector are from the top of the first operand, and the bottom of the second operand. This allows you to produce a new vector containing elements that straddle a pair of existing vectors. VEXT can be used to implement a moving window on data from two vectors, useful in FIR filters. **For permutation, it can also be used to simulate a byte-wise rotate operation, when using the same vector for both input operands.**

The following Neon GCC Intrinsic does the same as the assembly provided in the picture :

```
uint16x8_t vextq_u16 (uint16x8_t, uint16x8_t, const int)
```

So the the 24bit rotation over a full 128bit vector (not over each element) could be done by the following:

```
uint16x8_t input;
uint16x8_t t0;
uint16x8_t t1;
uint16x8_t rotated;

t0 = vextq_u16(input, input, 1);
t0 = vshlq_n_u16(t0, 8);
t1 = vextq_u16(input, input, 2);
t1 = vshrq_n_u16(t1, 8);
rotated = vorrq_u16(t0, t1);
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is over-complicated compared to `vextq_u8` to do the whole rotation in one instruction.

Answer (score 5):

Use `vext.8` to concat a vector with itself and give you the 16-byte window that you want (in this case offset by 3 bytes).

Doing this with intrinsics [requires casting](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472k/chr1359125040001.html) to keep the compiler happy, but it's still a single instruction:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

uint16x8_t byterotate3(uint16x8_t input) {
    uint8x16_t tmp = vreinterpretq_u8_u16(input);
    uint8x16_t rotated = vextq_u8(tmp, tmp, 16-3);
    return vreinterpretq_u16_u8(rotated);
}
```

`g++5.4 -O3 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon` ([on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Carm_neon.h%3E%0A%0Auint16x8_t+byterotate3(uint16x8_t+input)+%7B%0A++++uint8x16_t+tmp+%3D+vreinterpretq_u8_u16(input)%3B%0A++++uint8x16_t+rotated+%3D+vextq_u8(tmp,+tmp,+16-3)%3B%0A++++return+vreinterpretq_u16_u8(rotated)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:58.74704491725768,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm541,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1504567511579:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery321061962331942659341:(display:''),sizzle1504567511579:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1)),trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Darmv7-a+-mfloat-abi%3Dhard+-mfpu%3Dneon',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+5.4.1+(none)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:71.78217821782178,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+ARM+gcc+5.4.1+(none)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:28.21782178217822,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:41.25295508274232,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)) compiles it to this:

```
byterotate3(__simd128_uint16_t):
    vext.8  q0, q0, q0, #13
    bx      lr
```

A count of 16-3 means we left-rotate by 3 bytes.  (It means we take 13 bytes from the left vector and 3 bytes from the right vector, so it's also a right-rotate by 13).

---

Related: x86 also has instruction that takes a sliding window into the concatenation of two registers: [`palignr`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PALIGNR.html) (added in SSSE3).

---

Maybe I'm missing something about NEON, but I don't understand why the OP's self-answer is using `vext.16` (vextq_u16), which has 16-bit granularity.  It's not even a different instruction, just an alias for `vext.8` which makes it impossible to use an odd-numbered count, requiring extra instructions.  [The manual for `vext.8` says](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489f/CIHGAEFI.html):

> VEXT pseudo-instruction
>
> You can specify a datatype of 16, 32, or 64 instead of 8. In this
>   case, #imm refers to halfwords, words, or doublewords instead of
>   referring to bytes, and the permitted ranges are correspondingly
>   reduced.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure but I don't think NEON has rotate instructions.

You can compose the rotation operation you require with a left shift, a right shit and an or, e.g.:

```
uint8_t ror(uint8_t in, int rotation)
{
    return (in >> rotation) | (in << (8-rotation));
}
```

Just do the same with the Neon intrinsics for left shift, right shit and or.

```
uint16x8_t temp;
uint8_t rot;

uint16x8_t rotated =  vorrq_u16 ( vshlq_n_u16(temp, rot) , vshrq_n_u16(temp, 16 - rot) );
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift "Implementing circular shifts."

This will rotate the values inside the lanes. If you want to rotate the lanes themselves use VEXT as described in the other answer.

Comment: I'm not asking how to do a circular rotation in c ! I'm asking how to do it using Neon Intrinsics !

Comment: OK, I've added the actual intrinsic calls.

Comment: This is less bad than the OP's answer (3 instructions instead of 5), but unless `vext.8` is really slow compared to the byte-shift instructions, it's still inefficient.